# How to solve ReactRouterDOM is not defined error?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I keep getting the `ReactRouterDOM` error but I am following a tutorial and my professor is not getting this error (video may be outdated).

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Routing</title>

    <!-- Load Babel -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="root"></div> <!--- element we're going to target calling it root-->
 
  <!-- Load React -->
  <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->


  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 
  <!-- Load our React component. -->
  <script src="index.js" defer type="text/babel"></script>
  <script src="home.js" defer type="text/babel"></script>
  <script src="about.js" defer type="text/babel"></script>
  <script src="products.js" defer type="text/babel"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
function Spa(){
  const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
  const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
  const HashRouter = ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter;
     
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div>
        <h1> Hello World </h1>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link> --
        <Link to="/about/">about</Link> --
        <Link to="/products/">products</Link> 
        <hr/>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about/" exact component={about} />
        <Route path="/products/" exact component={products} />
      </div>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}

//Loads application
ReactDOM.render(
  <Spa/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I've already tried adding

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router'
```

and many variations and am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your script you need to reference the react router package like you do with `React` for `react` and `ReactDOM` for `react-dom`.

From what I can tell `react-router-dom` is exported as `ReactRouterDOM`.

Load the CDN links for the specific version of `react-router-dom` being used. Current is v6.14.2. Looks like you are trying to use v5 though.

```html
<!-- Load React Router and React Router DOM -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router@5.3.4/umd/react-router.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.3.4/umd/react-router-dom.js" crossorigin></script>
```

or if you want the production versions:

```html
<!-- Load React Router and React Router DOM -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router@5.3.4/umd/react-router.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.3.4/umd/react-router-dom.min.js" crossorigin></script>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this but I'm still getting errors

createContext.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createContext')

react-router.js:171 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createContext')

index.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at <anonymous>:3:14

Comment: @makimaki Those seem like errors/issues related to React. Try using ***just*** the development scripts or ***just*** the production ones. In the meantime I'll see if I can stand up a running sandbox demo.

Answer (score 0):

This error "any name" is not defined ... occurs when you are using something in your react app but have not imported it correctly in your code. To fix it you need to import 'react-router-dom' properly. You can fix this error by following below steps.

1. Install 'react-router-dom' using npm, yarn or pnpm if you haven't already;

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

or

```
yarn add react-router-dom
```

or

```
pnpm install react-router-dom
```

2. Update your index.js to import the necessary components from react-router-dom:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'; // This imports necessary components

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home Component</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About Component</h2>;
}

function Products() {
  return <h2>Products Component</h2>;
}

function Spa() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter> {/* Use BrowserRouter instead of HashRouter */}
      <div>
        <h1> Hello World </h1>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link> --
        <Link to="/about/">about</Link> --
        <Link to="/products/">products</Link> 
        <hr/>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about/" exact component={About} />
        <Route path="/products/" exact component={Products} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

//Loads application
ReactDOM.render(
  <Spa/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

use BrowserRouter instead of HashRouter, which provides cleaner URLs without the '#' symbol. We also import Route, Link, and BrowserRouter from react-router-dom instead of ReactRouterDOM.

Answer (score -1):

ReactDOM available since version 0.14.0.
You Can Also do the same by this as well.

```
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {


const router = createBrowserRouter([
{
  path: "/admin",
  element: <AdminLayout />,
},
{
  path: "/AboutUs",
  element: <AboutUsLayout />,
},
{
  path: "/",
  element: <Home />,
},
]);
return (
<RouterProvider router={router} />
)}
```